# Weird characters after processing a xml file in android

Tags: java, android, xml, encoding

I am making an andorid applicaiton which loads data from a xml file. The problem is that the xml file is not processed correctly and I am not able to serialize it, because of that. I think the problem is related to the encoding of the file.

How I made the xml file? From Eclipse I have clicked on New-> File -> and created a blank xml, then I've filled it with the needed information.

Here is how the xml looks in the editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<categories>
    <category value="Inbox"/>
    <category value="Private"/>
    <category value="Work"/>
    <category value="Business"/>
</categories>

<todos>
    <todo>
        <id>1</id>
        <text>Explore the app!</text>
    </todo>

    <todo>
        <id>2</id>
        <text>Add more todos!</text>
       <date>2013-05-09 12:21:55 CET</date>
   </todo>
</todos>
</data>
```

I am getting the xml file from res/xml and then I load the file in an Input Stream. After that I am converting the file to a String using the String constructor.

Here is the java code:

```
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.startingdata);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int next = is.read();
    while (next > -1) {
        bos.write(next);
        next = is.read();
    }
    bos.flush();
    byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
    xmldata = new String(result,"UTF-8");
```

after this step, I show the new xmldata to a Toast, to check how it looks. However I receive part of the data, plus some weird characters. What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!
I am attaching an image from my testing device, in order to show you the weird toast result:

[image]

Comment: After looking into the weird characters I am seeing that they are coming from the '<' open tags and <foobar/> tags. Because I can count four 8 #@$!#@!@ which i think represents <category/> and ten $ #@#@#@# which probably represents the open tags in the file. I am not sure about this, but it could be possible. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the encoding of your xml as UTF 8. You can do so by right clicking on your file and then set File Encoding from the drop down.

Comment: I right-clicked on the file, -> Properties, -> Text file encoding. Then i clicked on Other and clicked on UTF-8 from the drop-down. However after testing the app, I still have the problem.

Comment: actually u will not be able to print the utf-8 characters on console. You need to change the properties of console in eclipse by doing: Go ro Run Configuration->Common->Encoding (UTF 8)

Comment: Hello Juned, I am not using the console to print the information, but a Toast which is showed in the application, on start-up.

Comment: Thanks @JunedAhsan . I am using an XML parsing library for an Android app I am  working on and was seeing wierd characters in some places. Turns out I have set wrong encoding for parsing.